# Request for member ‘mCar’ in ‘this’, which is of non-class type ‘owner* const’

Tags: c++, oop, methods

I created a method to swap the cars from the owners.

```
bool owner::changeCar(owner& other, car& mCar){
  if(this == &other) return false;
  car* m = &this.mCar;
  this->mCar =&mCar;
  other.mCar = m;
  return true;
}
```

But I receive the error

> Request for member ‘mCar’ in ‘this’, which is of non-class type ‘owner* const’

on the line `car* m = &this.mCar;`.

Someone know what I'm doing wrong.
The class owner have a private car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did it correctly in the line below; `this` is a pointer, hence you need `->` to access its member `mCar`. Furthermore, `mCar` is apparently already a pointer (at least you use it as one) so the `&` before it is redundant.

```
car* m = this->mCar;
```

Comment: Just to add, in this case i need to remove the & before the this.. the mCar is already a pointer.. so .. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

The reason your code does not compile is that `this` is a *pointer*, not a *reference*; therefore, you need to use `->` operator instead of the `.` operator.

Comment: Whereas using the standard library when possible is a good idea, in this case it won't work, as he wants to achieve something completely different. I wonder who up-voted it, though (but Ok, the first paragraph is of course absolutely correct)?

Comment: @ChristianRau Why wouldn't it? The OP says that he is trying to swap the cars from the owners, so a call to `std::swap` should do the trick, no?

Comment: He wants to swap them using a third party, doing just `owner.mCar = this->mCar; this->mCar = &mCar;`. I'm not sure `std::swap` or your other alternative achieves that (at least not alone).

Comment: @ChristianRau OP's code looks very much like a "classic" swap, he's just missing `other.` in the second line of the swap; it should be `this->mCar =&other.mCar;` It does not make much sense without it.

Comment: And the additional `mCar` parameter is there for the sake of confusion? I guess he just used the tradional triangle-swap-idiom and put in a third parameter, without realizing that he doesn't need a triangle-swap in this case.

Comment: If he just forgot the `other.`, then the `&` doesn't make any sense, as he clarified in other comments, that every car in this code is a pointer, except the `mCar` function argument.

Comment: @ChristianRau I think you are right, I got confused because of the naming (mXYZ usually means "member").

Answer (score 0):

In one line you write `this.mCar` and in the next `this->mCar`. Looks wrong, doesn't it? In this case the second version is correct, since `this` is a pointer to `owner` and not an object or reference of type `owner`.